# User abusing tag wiki edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, edit-ban

A user is making several edits that I have rejected, and we need a moderator to intervene. Yes, I already tried to flag, and I'm not sure it worked. What do I do in these circumstances?

#### Copied Content

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5421850
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5421905
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5421783
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5421767

#### From Wikipedia

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5422002
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5422054

Comment: Could you explain why making lots of edits is abusive? Glancing through most look okay... (not fantastic by any means but something there is better than nothing)

Comment: *Please* don't call out specific users in this sort of context, or hundreds of people will end up descending on their profile which brings _their entire history_ under scrutiny. That's not a position I'd wish for anyone to be in :)

Comment: I've rejected several of his posts for 'Wiki not helpful' and 'Copied Content'.

Comment: Please link the specific edits then, cause this user has a lot of them.

Comment: I just checked a few that contain word for word copied text from other resources.

Comment: Example http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5421766 from [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html) and [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames)

Comment: @Tanner I don't see the issue they are adding a description where there wasn't one before so surely that's better then nothing regardless of the resource it's taken from? Taking into consideration attribution ofc.

Comment: @Lankymart Plagiarized content is *not* better than no content at all.  In addition to the legal and ethical points, it's simply not helpful content as a tag wiki.  Tag wiki's aren't' encyclopedia entries for those topics.

Comment: @Servy What are they then because that's exactly what I thought they were?? Someone doesn't know what a particular tag is for, quick paragraph or two with useful resources bang you're done!

Comment: @Lankymart Tag wikis are there to determine whether or not you should be using that tag for a particular question; it's about explaining what is and is not in scope in that tag.  What you are describing is what something like Wikipedia is for.  If that's what you want, go there.

Comment: @Servy Whoops silly me there's me thinking this site was for "programmers".

Comment: @Lankymart Why does the fact that this site is for programmers mean that tag wikis should be encyclopedias and not descriptions of how to use the tag?

Comment: @Servy Look obviously you feel strongly about this I personally feel that some information is better then none in this case, what's the point in stumbling across an empty tag wiki argument. But I respect your opinion.

Comment: @Lankymart It's not just my opinion. It's the site's policy.  That is waht tag wikis are designed to be, not just what I think they should be.  Tag wikis shouldn't be plagiarizing content not just because I believe it, but because of site policy.  If you have a problem with a tag not having a tag wiki then *go write actual proper tag wikis* rather than including, or approving the inclusion of, unhelpful plagiarized content.  If you just want to help construct encyclopedia entries for various topics then Wikipedia is the correct place to provide such contributions.

Comment: @Lankymart Though a site for programmers, that doesn't mean Stack Overflow is an encyclopedia. It's a question and answers site. Everything that is done on Stack Overflow should be done with the purpose of improving the volume/quality/categorization of the questions and answers.

Comment: @mason Yeah think Sevy covered it thx. Not into popularity contest though...yawn

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If their edits *are* bad, they will be [automatically blocked after enough have been rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78192/165773) - it's automatic and doesn't require the intervention of a moderator. You're welcome to flag, but realize that Stack Overflow has *at least* a thousand pending flags at any given time on average - so the response might not be immediate.

There's *bad* edits, and then there's *meh* edits. A user simply filling out tag wiki content that *doesn't* simply copy from other sources isn't necessarily *bad*, and we do encourage these edits by rewarding them with reputation. They can only get, at max, about a thousand rep through doing this so it's not the end of the world if they rack up a few hundred rep by filling out empty tag wikis.

If it's *truly* abusive, as in someone is defacing a lot of content *and people are actually approving it*, then we've probably got a ring of some sort on our hands, and that definitely requires alerting folks here, and pointing it out specifically. However, it's *quite* rare that it happens, so it's best to just let the review system handle it.

In cases where they're just copying content from other sites, it's .. messy. Sometimes the best 'elevator pitch' for a library or tool is the one that's .. well .. *on their site*, but the copy should indicate that, otherwise just reject it. If it's a wholesale copying issue on a larger scale, then flag as you have and mods will be in contact with them.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I should make this a question of its own, but considering the important amount of flags waiting for review, would you approve of rolling back to its previous state in case of licensed content and simply editing & moving on for missing attribution?

Comment: Wow!!! never knew that people can earn rep through tag wikies as well? don't interpret my comment -ve'ly. I am just surprised to know the fact.

Comment: There are also badges for editing tag wikis, the achievement of which which I think may be driving some of this high-volume/low-quality editing.

Comment: @AndrewMedico & Rahul But when you consider the state of many tag wikis, I'm not sure that much harm may be done. Besides, you only get a +2 rep if I'm not mistaken. I can't see why people would bother creating a tag and leave its wiki blank...